# how to redirect traffic only when the visitor first arrive?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, redirect

how to redirect traffic only when the visitor first arrive?

I prefer in php would be nice, or javascript is also fine.

Comment: Elaborate on *redirect* and *first arrive*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a splash page?

The first time they come to your page you [create a cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) using php.

```
setcookie("returning", TRUE);
```

So, that means on each page you check to see if they are a new visitor

```
if(emptyt($_COOKIE['returning'])) 
{
    setcookie("returning", TRUE, time()+60*60*24*365); // Expires in a year
    header('Location: /path/to/splash_page.php');
    exit();
}
// continue..
```

Comment: what should be the approach if cookies are not supported?

Comment: thanks, this should do it. How bout in Javascript, anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

If cookies are not an option, you could keep a table of IP addresses.  When the user arrives, note their IP address and check the IP address table to see if that address has visited before.  If not, add the address the IP table and redirect them to the "first time visitor" page.  If the address is in the table, proceed as normal.

Comment: Very bad idea since IPs change almost every request for some users. We are at the end of the IP4 lifespan after all.

Comment: @Xeoncross:  Every request? That would be new to me. If that was the case, you could mix in a session id, so at least the user would be recognized for the duration of their visit.  You could probably also say that setting a cookie is a bad idea since users can clean out cookies at any given time - some browsers can be configured to do it automatically when shut down.  Given the conditions of the question, this is a alternate approach and I'm sorry to have dissappointed you, I guess.

Watch out for those monkeys.

Comment: Yes, splash pages aren't used often for these reasons. It's hard to make sure visitors aren't sent there twice or more. However, almost every useragent supports cookies and has them enabled (far better ratio to static ips) so this is usually the safest way to do it. And if they clear their cookies - then they just have to watch it again ;)

Comment: I do have to agree - cookies are the way to go for this kind of thing.  In the end, I think the ultimate solution is to find a way to avoid the splash page altogether.  It's kind of like "skip intro" - if you have to provide a "skip intro" button, you should really ditch the intro.  Sorry if I was snippy in my previous comment.